# Does returning early prevent map() from iterating over the entire array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-map

Does the slice method iterate over the entire array? For example here I check what index and stop map when its on 4-th element. Do I have to do like that or is it better to just slice the array?

```
{data?.map((direction, i) => {
  if (i === 4) {
    return;
  }
  return (
    <Link
        className="hover:underline"
        key={direction.id}
        to={{
            pathname: '/courses',
            search: `?searchFilter%5B0%5D=${direction.id}`,
        }}
        onClick={scrollToTop}
    >
        {direction?.name}
    </Link>
  );
})}
```

My attempt is shown above

Comment: *"and stop map when its on 4-th element"*: your map with not stop; it will continue with a next call with index 5 if that index exists.

Comment: but it will loop the entire array either way . if you want to stop at 4 you should do a `for` loop instead.

Comment: I'd also suggest you reconsider your wording, as most visiting this question will assume you are referring to the [JS Array `.slice()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice), as opposed to your own attempt at truncating a dataset with a `.map()` method.

Comment: On practice my solition returns only four first elements from array that contains six elements

Comment: To use only the first four items of returned `data`, you could just truncate the array with `.slice()` higher up in your function (outside of the JSX `return`) and then just `.map()` that truncated array in its entirety in the JSX.

Comment: *"is it better to just slice the array"* This would solve your problem and I can not find a reason why you shouldn't.

Comment: *my solition returns only four first elements from array that contains six elements*: Once you've "sliced" the item at index 4, the item that was previously at index 5 is now at index 4 and will be removed, and the same for the item that was originally at index 6.

Comment: If you have an array with more than 4 elements, but you only want 4, you don't have to call any function. You can just set `.length` to 4.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm asking. What if i have an array than includes over 10000 elements? Will slice iterate through the entire array to return new array with first four elements or not?

Comment: @NikitaIpatov I don't know, but I also would not be worried about that because simply setting `.length` to 4 will certainly not iterate through the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the slice method iterate over the entire array?

No, it iterates as many times as the size of your slice. And when you apply a `.map` call on that slice, it will only visit the elements in that slice.

> For example here I check what index and stop map when its on 4-th element.

That is a misunderstanding. That `return` is not stopping the map-callbacks to continue until the end of the array. If there is an index 5, your `map` callback will be called with that index too.

> Do I have to do like that or is it better to just slice the array?

As your alternative does not achieve what you want, there is no question about "better". Just slice:

```
data?.slice(0, 4)?.map((direction, i) => 
    ...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

> What if i have an array than includes over 10000 elements? Will slice iterate through the entire array to return new array with first four elements or not?

No, it will only iterate over the elements you've asked for. This is covered by the loop starting at Step 14 in [the specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-array.prototype.slice).

> Do I have to do like that or is it better to just slice the array?

You certainly *can* use `slice` and then `map`, making a temporary copy of a portion of the array and then mapping it.

Someday, you'll be able to use iterator methods to skip to the index you want, take only as many elements as you want, and map them, all without making a copy. More in [the TC39 proposal here](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-iterator-helpers). Applying that to your example would be `data?.take(4).map(/*...*/)` I believe.

Until then, you could write your own version of `take` and `map`, or use one of the "userland implementations" the TC39 proposal links to, or write your own simple utility function that maps a subset of the array. For example (off-the-cuff, untested):

```
function mapPartial(array, callback, start = 0, end = array.length) {
    const result = [];
    // ...add adjusting `start` and `end` to be within bounds here...
    for (let index = start; index < end; ++index) {
        const value = array[index];
        const mappedValue = callback(value, index, array);
        result.push(mappedValue);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Then you'd use `data && mapPartial(data, /*...callback...*/, 0, 4)`.

You might want to tweak the order of parameters.